# I get the error: ‘get’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++

I would like to use the method get from the class pair :

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

And I get error for this line :

```
auto f3=[](std::pair<double, double> p){return std::log(1 + std::get<0>(p) * std::get<1>(p));};
```

This error is :

> error: ‘get’ is not a member of ‘std’

However, seeing the examples of the std::get function from the library, I didn't make any syntax errors.

EDIT : the code is :

```
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(){
    long int n = 1000;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> X(0,1);
    std::exponential_distribution<double> Y(1);
    auto f3=[](std::pair<double, double> p){return std::log(1 + std::get<0>(p) * std::get<1>(p));};
```

Comment: Are you compiling as C++11 or later?

Comment: At a guess you need to include the [utility header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/get). Please show a [mre]

Comment: Your code works for me https://rextester.com/YOJRV88276

Comment: Yet I compile ic C++11

Comment: I edited my first message

Comment: I compile at the stream : "g++ -std=c++11 myfile.cpp -o myfile"

Comment: But you didn't include `<utility>`

Comment: Oh thank you, it works ! Now I see where are the libraries to include !